# Input fields are showing blank in Thymeleaf Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to create an edit form using springMvc and thymeleaf. Input fields are not getting populated with values returned from controller.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updatecustomer")
public String search(@ModelAttribute("customerDto") CustomerDto customerDto, Model model) {
    Customer customer = service.search(customerDto);
    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
    return "mypage";
}
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{updatecustomer}" th:object="${customerDto}">
    <label>Email: </label><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Generated html on browser:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
```

Debugging shows the values are present in controller and returned to view but the email input value is blank.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Thymeleaf code you are binding **customerDto** to a form

```
th:object="${customerDto}"
```

where in your controller you are passing customer data to **customer** attribute name

```
model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
```

You should match these two. For example change your Thymeleaf code to this

```
th:object="${customer}"
```

Comment: Because of @ModelAttribute("customerDto")  I think he can use th:object="${customerDto}"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should map inside your JSP, the entity "customer" in your Model, with its own field!

```
<label>Email: </label><input type="text" th:field="*{customer.email}" />
```

Try it and tell us!